# how to align 2d array elements to form a 3*3 matrix?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to display a 2d array that shows tic-tac-toe game. I want it to look like this:

> x o x
>   o x o
>   x o x

but when I wrote:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
            {
                cout << A[i][j];
                cout << setw(3);
            }
        }
```

it just displays:

> x o x o x o x o x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the inner loop insert statement

```
cout << endl;
```

Comment: @user4043493 No problem. Only your post was not clear enough because the images of the desired output and the actual output coincide,:)

Comment: @user4043493 Now it is better.:)

Answer (score 1):

Add a line break:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
        cout << A[i][j];
        cout << setw(3);
    }
    cout << endl; // <<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```